# Using offset and jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using offset() with the jquery slider and I am so close to achieving my goal, but it is off slighty. I have it animating using animate to the top CSS coordinates but if you check out: http://www.ryancoughlin.com/demos/interactive-slider/index.html - you will see what it is doing. My goal is to have it fadeIn() and display the value to the right of the handle. i know I can offset the text from the handle using a simple margin:0 0 0 20px.

The part is aligning #current_value to the right of the handle. Thoughts?
            var slide_int = null;

```
$(function(){

    $("h4.code").click(function () {
        $("div#info").toggle("slow");
    });

    $('#slider').slider({
        animate: true,
        step: 1,
        min: 1,
        orientation: 'vertical',
        max: 10,
        start: function(event, ui){
            $('#current_value').empty();
            slide_int = setInterval(update_slider, 10); 
        },
        slide: function(event, ui){
            setTimeout(update_slider, 10);  
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            clearInterval(slide_int);
            slide_int = null;
        }
    }); 
});
function update_slider(){
    var offset = $('.ui-slider-handle').offset();
    var value = $('#slider').slider('option', 'value');

    $('#current_value').text('Value is '+value).css({top:offset.top });
    $('#current_value').fadeIn();

}
```

I know I could use margin to offset it to match, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems. The first, like Prestaul said, the slider event fires at the "beginning" of the move, not the end, so the offset is wrong.  You could fix this by setting a timeout:

```
$(function(){
    slide: function(event, ui){
        setTimeout(update_slider, 10);
    },
    ...
});
function update_slider()
{
    var offset = $('.ui-slider-handle').offset();
    var value = $('#slider').slider('option', 'value');
    $('#current_value').text('Value is '+value).animate({top:offset.top }, 1000 )
    $('#current_value').fadeIn();
}
```

The second problem is that the move is instantaneous, while the animation is not, meaning that the label will lag behind the slider.  The best I've come up with is this:

```
var slide_int = null;

$(function(){
    ...
    start: function(event, ui){
        $('#current_value').empty();
        // update the slider every 10ms
        slide_int = setInterval(update_slider, 10);
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        // remove the interval
        clearInterval(slide_int);
        slide_int = null;
    },
    ...
});

function update_slider()
{
    var offset = $('.ui-slider-handle').offset();
    var value = $('#slider').slider('option', 'value');

    $('#current_value').text('Value is '+value).css({top:offset.top });
    $('#current_value').fadeIn();
}
```

By using `css` instead of `animate`, you keep it always next to the slider, in exchange for smooth transitions.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your help. I updated my question with my updated code and doesnt seem to be behaving correctly. Any ideas on what I did? It looks right, is it the location of my function? The value doesnt follow it with the new code. Thanks, Ryan

Comment: I've updated it accordingly.  Also slide_int should be outside of the $() function.

Comment: Hey Tyler, I updated my code again, it goes to say Step 1, then doesnt for the rest? Thoughts the function keeps calling every 10ms which makes it load to the eright of the handle correct? If it didnt it would be off? Just so im learning what is going on, thank you.

Comment: I got it working better now, I added in your .css instead of .animate, see if you click on the slider and the handle slides there but the label doesn't update until you click the handle again anyway to fix that? Also is it not possible to use animate? I kind of like that effect? Thanks a ton

Comment: The best I could get was for it to lag behind, or not be smooth (if the animate speed was too fast) like using .css. If you find a better way, let me know.

Comment: Ahh..I see. i will play around with it. Thanks again for all of your help on this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: the visible value in Jquery Ui slider lags behind from internal value. Fixed the problem by changing the slider event from "slide" to "change".

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a different event.  "slide" fires before the handle is moved so your value is ending up at the previous handle position.  Try the "change" event and see if that gets you there.