# Slider won't update properly

Tags: jquery

I am using the JQuery slider UI Widget.  I am getting weird problems when using two sliders in the same form.  I tried using only the slide option.  This creates a slider that can be dragged all the way to the end, but the value of the slider is less than the full value of the slider.  This problem is more apparent the faster you slide the slider.

I then added a change option.  The same function as the slide function.  This fixed my first problem.  But now every time I slide to a value, when I release, the value is incremented or decremented by 1.  I can't explain this at all.  Code is below.

```
$(function() {
$( "#minTixSlider, #minPriceSlider"  ).slider({
        value:0,
        min:0,
        max: 100,
        step: 1,
        slide: function() {
            $( "#minTix" ).val( $( "#minTixSlider" ).slider( "value" ));
            $( "#minPrice" ).val( $( "#minPriceSlider" ).slider( "value" ));                
        },
        change: function() {
            $( "#minTix" ).val( $( "#minTixSlider" ).slider( "value" ));
            $( "#minPrice" ).val( $( "#minPriceSlider" ).slider( "value" ));                
        }

    });

$( "#minTix" ).val( $( "#minTixSlider" ).slider( "value" ));
$( "#minPrice" ).val( $( "#minPriceSlider" ).slider( "value" ));    

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/745037/using-offset-and-jquery-slider).  Here is my updated code.

```
    function updateInputs() {
    $( "#minTix" ).val( $( "#minTixSlider" ).slider( "value" ));
    $( "#minPrice" ).val( $( "#minPriceSlider" ).slider( "value" ));
}
$(function() {
$( "#minTixSlider, #minPriceSlider"  ).slider({
        value:0,
        min:0,
        max: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui){
            setTimeout(updateInputs, 10);},
        change: function(event, ui){
            setTimeout(updateInputs, 10);}
    });

$( "#minTix" ).val( $( "#minTixSlider" ).slider( "value" ));
$( "#minPrice" ).val( $( "#minPriceSlider" ).slider( "value" ));    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the `step: 1,` line altogether?

Step by definition on jquery doc says:
"step: A function to be called after each step of the animation." This may be where the extra jump is occurring.

Comment: Step - Determines the size or amount of each interval or step the slider takes between min and max. The full specified value range of the slider (max - min) needs to be evenly divisible by the step.
Code examples

Initialize a slider with the step option specified.

    $( ".selector" ).slider({ step: 5 });

Get or set the step option, after init.

    //getter
    var step = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "step" );
    //setter
    $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "step", 5 );

It might be different for other widgets.